# Facebook's app permission message is vague and unhelpful

Tags: facebook, authentication, permissions

When I attempt to sign in to my site with my Facebook account, I receive a warning which is inaccurate:

```
Submit for Login Review
Some of the permissions below have not been approved for use by Facebook.
```

The permissions they refer to are listed below this message:

```
****** will receive the following info: your public profile, email address,
birthday, website and personal description.
```

The latter permissions do not map to the permissions in the Facebook App permissions list which you must be approved for:

- manage_notifications
- read_insights
- publish_actions
- read_friendlists
- manage_pages

I cannot for the life of me find out which permissions I should request approval for. All I want to do is use Facebook as a signin mechanism for our website ... that's it. My understanding is that this requires no approval at all, but clearly it does, otherwise I would not have received the "Submit for Login Review" message.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm not sure which documentation you're looking at, but for API versions `2.0` or higher, the only permissions you can request from end-users **without** submitting your use of them to Facebook for review are:

- public_profile
- user_friends
- email

If you have any permissions in the `scope` parameter of the Oauth/Login dialog other than the three listed above, users who aren't admins/developers/testers of the app won't be prompted to grant them (until you have them approved)

The list you can request without approval is mentioned in the following documentation:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1#categories

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the answer, because it is informative and points to exactly the documentation required to understand the issue. It turns out that the application I am working in (I am a new hire here and still learning the codebase) actually does want publish_actions permission. I had been told by the previous programmer that we only needed login permission, but it turns out this was inaccurate. When I found the Facebook connect code, I was able to confirm that we are indeed asking for more permissions than I thought.  Thanks very much for your answer.

Comment: The permissions you listed in your original question are considered 'extended' - these are shown on a second [or third] page of the dialog and grant significant access to act on a user's behalf, but for most developers, since version 2.0 the distinction between 'user permissions' and 'extended permissions' isn't as important as the distinction between 'reviewable' and 'allowed by default'

Answer (score 3):

When calling the FB api you have the option to set a thing called "scope". Here is an example of how this may look:

```
'Facebook' => array ( 
                                    "enabled" => true,
                                    "keys" =>
                                        array (
                                            "id" => "762xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                                            "secret" => "b1831068a1xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                                        ),
                                    "scope" => "email, user_about_me, user_birthday, user_hometown, manage_notifications , read_insights, publish_actions, read_friendlists, manage_pages"
            ),
```

If you are requesting more than:

```
public_profile
user_friends
email
```

You will need to have your app verified.

The solution to your problem is to limit the scope of information you want access to, so this would resolve your problem:

```
'Facebook' => array ( 
                                    "enabled" => true,
                                    "keys" =>
                                        array (
                                            "id" => "762xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                                            "secret" => "b1831068a1xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                                        ),
                                    "scope" => "email, public_profile, user_friends"
            ),
```

Answer (score 3):

For me this is worked.

Goto your app in Facebook. Then goto AppReview ->permissions and features. Then click on ->Get Advanced permission.